# How to keep the users login id for all classes

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm using netbeans and have created a bunch of forms text fields and buttons using the drag and drop gui.

I've created this nice login page where the user enters a user id and password from a local database, I want to store that entered user id to use on another form (a "my profile" page) to then query the database and fetch details about that user. To do this I'll need to store the userid as currentuser and use it in another class.

I've tried a lot of things but the problem is that where the user enters the data is in a private void method and I can't seem to get any variable out of that here's what it looks like.

```
private void jButton6MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    String sql = "select * from user where userid='" +userid.getText()
                + "' and password='" +password.getText()+"'";
    try {
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome"); 
            dispose();
            currentuser = rs.getString("userid");

            HomePageMember form5 = new HomePageMember();
            form5.setVisible(true);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                        "Sorry, Invalid Login ID or Password");
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }

public class LoginPage extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    private String currentuser; 
    public String getText()  {
        return this.currentuser; 
        // something like this, but it doesn't work
    }

//Then in another class have this
displayuserid.setText("currentuser")
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but begin with your code is pretty wierd :

- jButton6MouseClicked belongs to which class?
- 2 of your braces are never closing.

Now to give you an idea of how to proceed : 
- Let say your method jButton6MouseClicked belongs to a class LogIn. This class just needs a class attribute currentUser and a getter for this attribute. Then you set this attribute inside jButton6MouseClicked (the fact that it is private doesn't change anything), and so you can get this currentUser from any other class :

```
public class LogIn {

    private String currentUser;

    public String getCurrentUser() {
        return this.currentUser();
    }

    // ... Here code to get the user enter login and password

    private void jButton6MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {  

    // ... same code as yours

    } // Close the brace

} // And the second one
```

Now if you are using the LogIn class from elsewhere, let's say the instance of your class is called login, you can get the currentUser by calling :

```
login.getCurrentUser();
```